# Is it better to embed widgets on posts or pages?

Tags: multisite, widgets

I am seeking to create a member site with category hierarchy....Is it better to use posts or pages for the category hierarchy and widgets that show new groups etc..?

```
    Phila                         New York
```

Sports      Outdoors            Sports      Outdoors
NFL  NBA    Hiking  Rafting     NFL  NBA    Hiking Rafting

Comment: Why wouldn't you use _categories_ for the category hierarchy?

Comment: I have "posts"' and "pages" on my dashboard...nothing that says "categories"...only under posts...hence, my question